# Adding SignalR to existing IdentityServer4 Authorization

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-signalr

I have an Asp.Net core 2.2 IdentityServer4 application with a working system supporting claims, etc.  I'm adding SignalR to it and want to use the [Authenitcation] header and have access to the same claims my controllers have.

I've found a couple of articles on integrating SignalR with IdentityServer4, but I can't tell what is overlap with things I'm already doing and what's necessary to add support for SignalR.  Do I just need to inform IdentityServer of the specific SignalR route to authorize?

Here's a thorough article with an extensive example on GitHub:
https://mikebridge.github.io/articles/identityserver4-signalr/
https://github.com/mikebridge/IdentityServer4SignalR

Comment: Adding a link to the articles you are referring to may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up re-working my IdentityServer4 usage to create a jwtbearer token and use the HybridAndClientCredentials and the User claims were picked up in my signalr session start event.

Add Hybrid Client to IdentityServer4:

```
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "mvc",
            ClientName = "MVC Client",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

            ClientSecrets = 
            {
                new Secret("secret".Sha256())
            },

            RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc" },

            AllowedScopes = 
            {
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                "api1"
            },
            AllowOfflineAccess = true
        }
```

and then in startup on the mvc client:

```
 ServiceCollection.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                options.ClientId = "mvc";

                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                options.Scope.Add("api1");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("website", "website"); 
            });
```

This is modeled after the example: **Quickstart5_HybridAndApi**

In SignalR on server:

```
        [Authorize]
        public class SignalRSignalHub : Hub
        {
            public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
            {
                var context = Context.GetHttpContext();
                return base.OnConnectedAsync();
            }
        }
```