# Failed SignalR accentuations using Identity Server 4

Tags: authentication, identityserver4, jwt, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a set up of Identity Server 4, Asp.Net Core SignalR Hub, and JavaScript client.
When I try to connect to the SignalR Hub, the "negotiateVersion: 1" pass correctly but the request to the hub doesn't pass at all. The error in Chrome is "HTTP Authentication failed; no valid credentials available" and 401 status code in FireFox. The id and the access token are present in the query. I try different examples but with no desired result.

Versions:
Identity Server 4 - .Net Core 2.1

- IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity(2.5.0)

Asp.Net Core SignalR Hub - .Net Core 3.1

- IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation(3.0.1)
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer(3.1.7)

JavaScript Client

- signalr.min.js v4.2.2+97478eb6

Here is my configuration in Identity Server:
Config.cs

```
ClientId = "my.client",
AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
AllowedScopes =
{
    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
    "api1"
},
Claims = { },
RedirectUris = {
    "https://mySite/popupFrame.html",
    "https://mySite/silentFrame.html",
},
PostLogoutRedirectUris = {"https://mySite/logoutFrame.html" },
RequireConsent = false,
AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
AccessTokenLifetime = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).TotalSeconds,
```

Startup.cs in ConfigureServices method

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
.AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
.AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
.AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
.AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
.AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
.AddResourceOwnerValidator<ResourceOwnerValidator>()
.AddProfileService<ProfileService>();

services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, AppClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

Here is my configuration in Asp.Net SignalR:
Startup.cs in ConfigureServices method

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://localhost:44341";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.ApiName = "api1"; 
        options.JwtBearerEvents = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnMessageReceived = context =>
            {
                StringValues queryAccessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                PathString path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                if (path.StartsWithSegments("/brokerhub") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryAccessToken)) 
                {
                    context.Token = queryAccessToken;
                }
                
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
        };
    });

services.AddCors();
services.AddSignalR();
services.AddControllers();
```

Startup.cs in Configure method

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors(builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins("https://mySite", "http://localhost")
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .WithMethods("GET", "POST")
        .AllowCredentials();
});

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapHub<BrokerHub>("/brokerhub", options =>
    {
        options.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
    });
});
```

The Hub controller

```
[Authorize]
public class BrokerHub : Hub
```

And finally the JS Client

```
client = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl('https://hub.com/brokerhub/', {
            accessTokenFactory: () => {
                return user.access_token;
            }
        })
        .build();
```

Can anyone point me what I'm missing in configurations?

Comment: Hi, @Antonio Iliev, Does it works on Edge or IE? Try `AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials`. You could check  [Adding SignalR to existing IdentityServer4 Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53864445/adding-signalr-to-existing-identityserver4-authorization)

Comment: Hi @MichaelWang. Thank you for your quick response. I have the same error message in Edge and IE totally doesn't work :) . I try with the Hybrid grant type, but unfortunately, the Identity Server is throwing the "Invalid grant type for client: implicit" and refuse to authenticate the user. Thank you for the link, but the ASP.Net Core 3.1 changed the API for the services and doesn't contain the AddOpenIdConnect method anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this issue is relevant - https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2349#issuecomment-394099795

Can you please try to use *options.TokenRetriever* instead of *OnMessageReceived* as shown in the link above and introduce CustomTokenRetriever?